# Trouble converting for loops in Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop

So I need to convert a set of nested for loops from Matlab to Python, and I'm a bit stuck.

I have tried a bunch of options, and am currently stuck on the code shown below.

Also a and tau are the same for both codes.

The Matlab code:

```
for j=1:161
    te = 1:j;
    j
    for i=te
        i
        G(i) = E_C(i)*(a(1)*exp(-(length(te) i+1)./tau(1))+a(2).*exp(-(length(te)-i+1)./tau(2))+a(3).*exp(-(length(te) i+1)./tau(3))+a(4).*exp(-(length(te)-i+1)./tau(4))+a(5).*exp(-(length(te)-i+1)./tau(5)));
    end
    d(j)= sum(G)
end
dCppmv = d/1000;
```

My Pyton code, which is not giving the same results:

```
CO6=[]
for i in np.arange(161):
    a = [0.067, 0.1135, 0.152, 0.097, 0.041]
    tau= [inf, 313.8, 79.8, 18.8, 1.7]
    temp = np.arange(0,i)
    for j in temps:
        G = E_cc[j] *( ((a[0] * np.exp(-(len(temp)-j+1)))/tau[0]) +((a[1] * np.exp(-(len(temp)-j+1)))/tau[1]) +((a[2] * np.exp(-(len(temp)-j+1)))/tau[2]) +((a[3] * np.exp(-(len(temp)-j+1)))/tau[3]) +((a[4] * np.exp(-(len(temp)-j+1)))/tau[4])  )
        CO6.append(G/1000)
```

I have checked the G formula, and they should be the same. I'm pretty confident the problem is with the for-loops and the summing of G at the end.

Comment: You would enhance the chance of a reply if you could make life easier for the reader.

(a) put numerical constants in, rather than variables that we have to guess in the Matlab (b) use exactly the same variable names (not just similar) between the two
(c) remove the unnecessary lines, e.g. the stand-alone "i" and "j" in the Matlab (d) to my eyes, you seem to have swapped round the meaning of "i" and "j" between the languages. Is that intended?

All of these make it unnecessarily challenging.

Comment: (e) the "a" and "tau" in the Python could be defined
 before the "for i". (f) I don't see where, in the python, you are doing the summing.

Comment: Since your matlab code is full of syntax errors, it's hard to translate that to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step would be to simplify the matlab code:

```
for j=1:161
    for i=1:j
        p = -(j-i+1)./tau;
        G(i) = E_C(i) * sum(a .* exp(p));
    end
    d(j)= sum(G)
end
dCppmv = d/1000
```

Then the translation to python is much easier:

```
a = np.array([0.067, 0.1135, 0.152, 0.097, 0.041])
tau = np.array([np.inf, 313.8, 79.8, 18.8, 1.7])
d = []
for j in range(161):
    G = []
    for i in range(j):
        p = -(j-i+1)/tau
        G.append(E_cc[j] * sum(a * np.exp(p)))
    d.append(sum(G))
dCppmv = np.array(d)/1000
```